# Was Penguin always intended to be a main character in the Gotham TV series?

Tags: dc, character-development, gotham

In the television series *Gotham,* was the Penguin originally written as a main character, or [did the actor make the character so popular](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnsembleDarkhorse) the writers made the role bigger for him? (TVTropes warning)